# Trying to use valueOf with a generic enum class

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm making a class that takes in an **enum class** in it's constructor, the thing is that I want it to be able to take in any enum so I'm using the following generic definition: `<T extends Enum<T>>`.

My question is why can't I use `enumClass.valueof(string)`? (I get the following error: `The method valueOf(String) is undefined for the type Class<T>`). I've found that using `Enum.valueOf(enumClass, string)` works but I don't understand ***why***, any help is appreciated.

```
public class ValidadorEntradaEnum<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private final Class<T> enumClass;

    public ValidadorEntradaEnum(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public boolean containsString(String string) {
        try {
            Enum.valueOf(enumClass, string);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it work? `valueOf()` is a static method on `T`, not an instance method of `Class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***My question is why can't I use `enumClass.valueof(string)`?***

In your example, `enumClass` is of type `Class<T extends Enum<T>>`. So, if we look at the documentation for [java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html) and do a Ctrl+F for `valueOf`, we see that there is no such method called `valueOf`.

However, if we go to the documentation for `java.lang.Enum`, we see that there is a `valueOf` method, which takes in 2 parameters -- a `Class` with a type parameter of `<T extends Enum<T>>` and a `String`.

Let's say that I have an `enum` called `SomeEnum`.

```
enum SomeEnum
{

    SOME_ENUM_VALUE,
    ;

}
```

When I press compile, java takes this enum definition and turns it into a class with a couple of special methods. One of those methods is the `valueOf` method which takes in a `String`. This is the one you seem to want.

Let's say that I have a `String` that I want to convert into `SomeEnum`.

```
final String someString = "SOME_ENUM_VALUE";
```

So then your question is, why can't I do `enumClass.valueOf(someString)`?

The problem is, `enumClass` is a `Class<T extends Enum<T>>`, not an `enum`. You probably did something like this to get `enumClass` populated.

```
final Class<T extends Enum<T>> enumClass = SomeEnum.class;
```

But remember, `java.lang.Class` does not have the `valueOf` method! The only ones that have `valueOf` is `java.lang.Enum` and this `SomeEnum` that I made!

I think I see the reason why you are confused.

Some people see this...

```
SomeEnum.valueOf(someString)
```

...and think that it is equivalent to typing this...

```
SomeEnum.class.valueOf(someString)
```

...which is incorrect.

`SomeEnum` represents your enum's class and gives up the static methods, fields, and values.

`SomeEnum.class` represents your enum's CLASS FILE! It's job is to DESCRIBE your enum's capabilities, but it cannot USE any of the capabilities of your enum!

Because if so, then you could do this.

```
SomeEnum.class.valueOf(someString) //WRONG, not possible
```

`SomeEnum.valueOf(someString)` just means "call the static method `valueOf` on `SomeEnum` for the parameter `someString`"

Now, if your next question is, how do I get the static method `valueOf` when I only have a `java.lang.Class`? Well, the easiest way is to use `Enum.valueOf(someClass, someString)`, just like you already found. That's literally the reason why they created that method. They knew that someone like you would come around asking how to turn a `String` into an enum when you only have the `Class` of the enum. So, they made that method.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could check if I am using the terminology correctly. I know that I am right, but I feel like I am using the wrong words to describe. Particularly the part where I said "**represents your enum's CLASS FILE**"

Comment: Your suspicion is right. A `Class` obj describes the runtime class, not a class file. This even includes the artifacts of the actual `enum` type, like the `valueOf(String)` method. E.g. you can use `SomeEnum.class.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, "SOME_ENUM_VALUE")`. However, the API of the class `Class` itself is designed to be suitable to all classes, not only enum classes. A `valueOf` method would be possible, just like `getEnumConstants()` exists, but it could not prevent wrong usage. In contrast, `Enum.valueOf(…, …)` can enforce a `Class<T>` (`T extends Enum<T>`) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The one-argument `valueOf()` method and the `values()` method are static methods that are defined on each enum type, as specified in the "[Enum Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3)" section of the Java Language Specification.

They are not "inherited" from the `Enum` class or any other class, since static methods cannot be overridden in Java. So you will not see these methods in the Java standard library documentation. Unlike with instance methods, which class a static method is called on is fixed at compile time. To call a static method, you would either 1) explicitly specify the name of a class, like `<name of class>.<static method name>()`, 2) call it without explicitly qualifying it, like `<static method name>()`, or 3) call it on an expression, like `<some expression>.<static method name>()`. If you use the #1, it will call the method of the named class. If you use #2, it will call the method of the class the code is in. If you use #3, it will use the compile-time type of the expression as the class to use. Counterintuitively, it will not use the runtime value of the expression. So even if the runtime value of the expression was a reference to a subclass which has a static method of the same name, or the runtime value of the expression was `null`, it will still call the static method on the compile-time type.

The `Enum` class does not define the `values()` or one-argument `valueOf()` static methods. Even if it did, these methods would be useless -- you would not be able to use them to call the `values()` or one-argument `valueOf()` static methods of an enum type, because the class that a static method is called on is determined at compile time. There is no way in Java to call a static method on a class that is determined dynamically at runtime, except using reflection. You cannot just call the static method on the `Class` instance representing your enum type, because static methods are not methods on the `Class` instance -- only the [methods documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) as methods of the `Class` class can be called on `Class` instances.

So if you wanted, you could call the one-argument `valueOf()` method on your class via reflection, and it would work:

```
Method m = enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
T value = (T) m.invoke(null, string);
```

The authors of the Java standard library decided to provide a convenience API to accomplish this without reflection, by providing the two-argument `Enum.valueOf()` method, as you have discovered: `T value = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, string)`.  This two-argument `Enum.valueOf()` method is completely unrelated to the one-argument `valueOf()` method of enum types, other than having the same name. It is not some magical syntax that allows you to call a static method on a dynamically-determined class by calling it with two arguments -- it is just simply a separate API provided for this one use case.

---

(As an aside, the same thing is true for the `values()` static method of enum types. There is no way to call it on a class dynamically determined at runtime, except using reflection. You can achieve it using reflection, and it works:

```
Method m = enumClass.getMethod("values");
T[] values = (T[]) m.invoke(null);
```

However, they also provided a convenience API to achieve this without reflection -- the `getEnumConstants()` method on the `Class` class representing the enum type: `T[] values = enumClass.getEnumConstants()`.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Class.getEnumConstants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) to get the enum values of an enum from its class object. Each enum value has a `value` which you can then use to determine if your enum contains the string you're checking.

Comment: Using `Class#getEnumConstants()` is a misleading way to do it. It gives you an array of values, and then you must call `#valueOf(String)` on one of the values. `#valueOf(String)` on one of the values is problematic because it is implied that you are validating if the incoming String matches the enum ***value*** as opposed to the enum itself. And even ignoring that, the question is asking why it is not possible. They already found the alternative, which is the correct way of doing what you are trying to do.